# Block restriction

Tags: 7, views, blocks, uri

I have content with URLs in the following pattern:

> `http://example.com/subdirectory/working-site/major-event-2/event/4580/speakers`

There is a Views generated Block which I am trying to restrict to the display only for the following pattern:

> event/*/speakers

It seems correct to me but whenever I try it, my block does not display.

This should be really simple but I wonder if anyone can help by telling me what I'm doing wrong which is preventing my block from displaying?

Comment: Shouldn't you use "%"? `event/%/speakers`?

Comment: what is your base_url?

Comment: @Bhuvana: The base_url is http://example.com/subdirectory

Comment: @Djouuuuh: I tried the % but it did not work

Comment: can you try /major-event-2/event/*/speakers

Answer (score 0):

If base url is this

> example.com/subdirectory/

this might help you

> working-site/major-event-2/event/*/speakers

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there, based on your pattern the visibility settings assume that the URL will start with **event** so just change it to this:

```
*/event/*/speakers
```

That will allow anything before the event as well (given that you have the event name etc in after the base URL).

You can have any number of wildcards in the pattern and the wildcard is a `*` for visibility settings, `%` is used in functions like `hook_menu` for wildcards.